# Blank Page Laravel: 50k+ table entries

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel-4

I'm trying to display data obtained from a database on a simple html page. The code works fine with smaller entries. When i query a larger database (50k+ entries), it returns a blank page. So i am of the assumption that the size of the table is the issue here, i do not recieve any error reports whatsoever. Can someone take a look at my code and advice on how i can deal with this?

Model:

```
 <?php
 //Model (file name: Completion)
 class Completion extends Eloquent{
 protected $table = 'completion_date';
 public $timestamps = false;
 }
```

Controller:

```
 class CompletionController extends BaseController  {
     public function index()    {
         $lsz = Completion::all();
         return View::make('completion.lsz', ['completion' => $lsz]);
     }    
 }
```

Route:

```
 Route::get('/Completion', 'CompletionController@index');
```

Comment: turn on error reporting.

Comment: use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `display_errors(1)`. I think, there are a timeout error, what you do not see, because you do not displays your errors.

Comment: I've set **debug = true;**, and added **error_reporting(E_ALL);** and **display_errors(1)** to my index.php file. Problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/config/app.php and set debug to true. Try to use paginate for split your database queries.

```
$lsz = Completion::paginate(100);
```

Comment: Where does this come in? Controller or Model?